# Load node.js module dynamically into another node.js module running as a Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Inside the Lambda Function (a node js module), I want to dynamically load another node js module based on request parameters. The node js modules to be loaded dynamically should exist in S3 buckets?

Requesting for your help and support for this use case?
Thank You

Comment: I don't believe in Lambda you can load a module dynamically from another S3 bucket. Every module that you want to use must be included in the same Lambda package. I don't even believe you can `require` any other module based on a variable in node.js. So, no `require('foo-' + bar)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you can do this.

- `GetObject` from `S3`.
- Read the content as String
- Use [require-from-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-from-string) or [module-from-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-from-string) library to load as a module.

In practice, doing something like this from a `Lambda` may not make a lot of sense. You are billed per millisecond. Even though you want to load from S3, it still is a network call (Think some latency here!). You'll pay for the S3 requests as well. If you have a decent traffic and based on the number of such files you want to load, the solution may not be very cost, performance effective.

Consider the possibility of packaging all the files that you need to load with your lambda code (Can cause slow start due to package size). Then lazily load the required modules as per request.